# SQL Server: why are two foreign keys allowed on a column referencing to single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does SQL Server allow this?

```
create table dbo.tab1 
(
    id int primary key
)

create table dbo.tab2 
(
    id int constraint first_name references tab1(id),
    constraint second_name foreign key (id) references tab1(id) 
 )
```

Comment: Question is "why not?".

Comment: You have defined two constraints with two different names.  That is allowed, although I cannot see any actual purpose for it.

Comment: It's also possible to create two check constraints where either one, individually, may produce the same overall result - but they could each be arbitrarily complex (i.e. maybe one uses `BETWEEN` and the other enumerates allowed values in an `IN`) - where should the dividing line be?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that might clarify this a bit.

I have a person table which defines all of the people in the system.  I then have a marriage table.  A marriage is defined as a pairing of 1 Husband and 1 Wife, and both of these need to be valid entries in the Person table.

```
create table dbo.Person
(
    id int primary key
)

create table dbo.Marriage
(
    id int constraint Husband references tab1(id),
    id2 int constraint Wife foreign key (id) references tab1(id) 
 )
```

Example was for clarity.  Please forgive me for any political or cultural assumptions that may have gone into it.

Comment: I like the example; had a similar thought; though mine was an org chart with manager/direct report.

Comment: But this Marriage table only allows marriages of a person with themselves - there's a single `id` column, it can only store one value. As in the OPs tables as well.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. This is quite interesting functionality wise. See if you are using parent child concept then it's helpful.

**Example:** If you have customer and dbo.Customer table. The customer distribute the commission after some recharge. So when you relate Customer to its parent chain you need the same column of customer table as foreign key twice.

Comment: Would you please elaborate further?